# Does a continuously running furnace pilot light need a spark ignitor?

Tags: furnace

I have a very old gas furnace with a continuously running pilot light.  The system has a spark ignitor that has recently gone bad but I'm wondering why the furnace ever had the ignitor installed if the pilot light is constantly on?  I assumed spark ignitors were only necessary for furnaces that didn't have a continuously running pilot light.

The picture does not have the pilot light running. [image: pilot light setup]

Comment: Can you post a photo of the caution label on the furnace that discusses how to light the gas valve, the wiring diagram for the furnace, or the make and model of this furnace for that matter? "Spark to pilot" gas ignition systems were, and still are used....

Answer (score 2):

> Does a continuously running furnace pilot light need a spark igniter?

It does not "NEED" one as the pilot light can also be lit with match or a lighter but it is  **more convenient to use the igniter**. The igniter is only needed if the pilot goes out and needs to be re-lit.

**The igniter is for lighting the pilot light, not the furnace.**

If you ever have to shut your gas off for any reason,  such as service  or vacation or if the pilot  just goes out, you can use the igniter to light the pilot light.

Once the pilot light is lit it stays on (*should stay on*) and when the furnace needs to fire up the constant pilot provides the flame needed to ignite the burners.

Most, if not all, modern appliances that have combustion now have electronic spark igniters so  there is no need to have a constantly lit pilot.

[Pilot Lights Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilot_light)

[Pilot Light Safety](https://www.nachi.org/pilot-lights.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Having spark ignition was a feature (so you did not have to use a match to light it)

I see these on motor homes and trailers that are designed for short use most often. If the igniter has failed and you want to use a match or lighter that is fine and it won’t be a problem. I know I have replaced them for less than 10$ for a generic one years back. But if it is easy to light I would not worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that looks like an old conversion burner with a "flower pot" on the top. (that is what we called them). I would like to venture a guess that that ignitor was added and may be an old White Rodgers device that would relight the pilot any time the pilot flame was extinguished. I used to install them on units that suffered from frequent pilot outages. The only time that the ignitor would spark was when no flame was present and would spark any time the pilot would shut off. White rodgers has a model number 5059-134 and can be purchased at Supplyhouse.com. There may be other types available.  hope this is an answer that can help